# R 1000 rnorm samples

Tags: r, normal-distribution

x <- rnorm(25)  will produce a single sample of size 25 from the standard normal distribution.

How do I take 1000 samples of size 25 from standard normal distribution at the same time?

I would like to do this efficiently, so that I will be able to compute things such as the mean and standard deviation for each of the 1000 samples and compare them via a histogram.

[Also: I would then like to uniformally and randomly select one of these 1000 samples and bootstrap it]

Answer (score 2):

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(25000), 1000, 25)
```

Each row of X is a sample of size 25 from the standard normal distribution. There are 1000 rows.

Comment: rnorm(25000, 1000, 25)  will give you 25000 values from a normal distribution with mean of 1000 and sd of 25

Comment: Oops. Fixed it.

Comment: Why do you put 25000 in the rnorm( ) though?

Comment: If you want 1000 samples of 25 normals, you need 25000 total. This just arranges the 25K into a 1000 x 25 array.

Comment: Then how would I be able to select one sample out of the 1000 uniformly?

Comment: I don't know why this answer was downvoted. It shows the standard approach of doing this in R. @MattJ You simply select a row of the matrix.

Comment: How do I do this randomly in R?

Comment: @MattJ if you would like to `sample` one row randomly from `X` you can do: `X[sample(x = 1000, size = 1), ]`